# Understanding Haskell (<-) operator

Tags: haskell

I was studying the code over at https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Zebra_puzzle#LP-like_version and got somewhat confused.

Here is a minimal example of what is going on in that code.

```
import Control.Monad
import Data.List

values :: (Bounded a, Enum a) => [[a]]
values = permutations [minBound..maxBound]

data Nation = English | Swede | Dane
  deriving (Bounded, Eq, Enum, Show)

data Color = Red | Blue | Green
  deriving (Bounded, Eq, Enum, Show)

answers = do

  nation <- values
  begin nation English

  color <- values
  end color Red

  return $ zip nation color

  where
    end xs x = guard $ last xs == x
    begin xs x = guard $ head xs == x

main :: IO ()
main = do
    forM_ answers $ (\answer ->  -- for answer in answers:
      do
        mapM_ print answer
        putStrLn "----" )
    putStrLn "No more solutions!"
```

what is mysterious for me is what is happening in the do block.

I understand from various sources that the `a <- b` operator does an action `b` and binds it to `a`. But what is the action here exactly?

I assumed it was `values` but if I comment out the `begin` and `end` function calls and definitions then haskell does not know what to do with `values` anymore. I guess this is because the equality test in their definitions is what lets haskell infer the type (am I wrong?).

1. In that case what exactly *is* the *action* here?
2. Also how does `values` know which bounded type to apply `permutations` to? This part seems quite mysterious.
3. Finally, if I wanted to keep the same
   code as above but modify it list out all permutations (not just the
   one that satisfy `begin` and `end`) how would I do it?

Comment: It's not technically an operator; it's just syntax for binding the result of the `>>=` operator to a name in an implicit function. `a <- b` is parsed as `b >>= (\a -> ...)`, where `...` is the rest of the `do` block.

Comment: Without `begin` and `end` (whose equality tests do indeed guide type inference, as only things of the same you're cam be tested for `==`), the type checker has no way to see that you're talking about `Nation`s and `Color`s. It just sees you want two types that are `Bounded`, `Enum`, and `Show`, and quite properly refuses to guess what you might mean.

Comment: Oh hell List Monad. Yeah well that's not exactly the most straightforward example.

Comment: A list comprehension would have been more idiomatic for this. This style is probably used to mimic logical programming, but it's not a very good style per se (IMO). (I also find `do..where` awful style)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can translate `do` notation to list comprehension notation pretty mechanically:

```
answers = [ zip nation color
          | nation <- values, head nation == English
          , color <- values, last color == Red
          ]
```

I really don't like this `head` and `last` business though.

Comment: Thanks. That helps. For (3), adding `answers :: [[(Nation, Color)]]` to the code helps list all permutations without the `nation` and `color`. And for (1) I understand it now as a bunch of nested actions. So only (2) needs clarification.

Comment: I suppose the type signature for answers helps values know which bounded type to act on as well. Oh well ... some of this seems like pure magic at times.

Comment: @IvanAbraham, well, `answers` doesn't even have a type signature. Type inference can indeed seem like magic sometimes, but it's really not. The key thing to remember is that type information can flow in all directions. In `color <- values`, the `color` value is determined by the `values` value, but the `values` type is determined by the `color` type. The compiler just propagates the equalities it discovers through a fairly standard process called *unification* to work out what the types have to be for everything to match up properly. To help you understand your code, however, it's

Comment: generally best to give type signatures to all top-level functions and all non-trivial local functions. Sometimes you'll need to use the `ScopedTypeVariables` extension for the latter.